# best c# syntax/idiom, reading array of friends from Facebook

Tags: c#, json, facebook-graph-api, dictionary, idioms

In c#, I'm simply grabbing "/me/friends" from the FB api,

```
private void FacebookFriends()
    {
    FB.API("/me/friends", HttpMethod.GET, FBAPIFriendsCallback);
    }

private void FBAPIFriendsCallback(FBResult response)
    {
    // (error handling here - no problem)

    // ugly code...
    var dict = Json.Deserialize(response.Text)
        as Dictionary<string,object>;
    var friendList = new List<object>();
    friendList = (List<object>)(dict["data"]);
    int _friendCount = friendList.Count;

    // ugly code...
    // (example shows getting one item, would loop through all)
    string id = getDataValueForKey(
          (Dictionary<string,object>)(friendList[0]), "id" );
    string name = getDataValueForKey(
          (Dictionary<string,object>)(friendList[0]), "name" );
    }
```

Notice the very, very ugly code -- what's the more elegant way to write this?  Cheers

---

In fact, per swazza's comment below, here's the full code passage:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Parse;
using System;
using Facebook;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using Facebook.MiniJSON;


public class ParseLinkOps : MonoBehaviour
  {

  ...

  public void GetFriendsFromFBThenMatch()
    {
    FB.API("/me/friends", HttpMethod.GET, _cbFriends);
    // FB calls at
    // https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/reference/current
    }

  private void _cbFriends(FBResult response)
    {
    // goal: given the json result from the cloud,
    // create a List<string> containing only the FacebookID "id" numbers

    if ( ! String.IsNullOrEmpty(response.Error) )
      { // .. error handling .. return; }

    var dict = Json.Deserialize(response.Text)
            as Dictionary<string,object>;

    var friendList = new List<object>();
    friendList = (List<object>)(dict["data"]);

    int _friendCount = friendList.Count;
    Debug.Log("Found friends on FB, _friendCount ... " +_friendCount);

    // so, convert that complex array of FB objects,
    // to simply an array of "id" strings
    // use very ugly code but assume someone on SO knows better later :-)

    List<string> friendIDsFromFB = new List<string>();

    for ( int k=0; k<_friendCount; ++k)
      {
      string friendFBID =
        getDataValueForKey( (Dictionary<string,object>)(friendList[k]), "id");

      string friendName =
        getDataValueForKey( (Dictionary<string,object>)(friendList[k]), "name");

      Debug.Log( k +"/" +_friendCount +" " +friendFBID +" " +friendName);

      friendIDsFromFB.Add( friendFBID );
      }

    // we're done, the list is in friendIDsFromFB
    StartCoroutine( _match( friendIDsFromFB ) );
    }

  ...
  }
```

Comment: Isn't this question more relevant on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: JW - possibly.  But C.R. is more for (let's say) "algorithmic" type of questions. this is a little more of a specific sort of "how to do X in Y" type of thing.  Anyway cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using linq extensions?

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, object>();
var friend = dict
            .Where(s => s.Key.Equals("data"))
            .Select(s => new { Id = s.Key, Name = s.Value })
            .First();

var friendId = friend.Id;
var friendName = friend.Name;
```

Here is a linq extension to iterate over an enumerable and perform an action on each element -

```
public static void Execute<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Action<TSource> actionToExecute)
{
    if (source.Count() > 0)
    {
        foreach (var item in source)
        {
            actionToExecute(item);
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: So I understand that you are using this in Unity game engine. Its been ages since I worked on Unity. Glad to know they have support for Linq now. So here is the code that I wrote that get the friendIds. There is some code that is specific to ASP.Net but the linq part should work anywhere -

```
// Use ASP.Net's Javascript serializer to desrialize the json response received from 
// call to graph.facebook.com/me/friends
var jsSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var jsonString = "{ \"data\": [ { \"name\": \"name1\", \"id\": \"id1\" }, { \"name\": \"name2\", \"id\": \"id2\" } ] }";

// Deserialize the json to type - Dictionary<string, object>
var dict = jsSerializer.Deserialize(jsonString, typeof(Dictionary<string, object>)) as Dictionary<string, object>;

/*Code upto here is specific to ASP.Net - At this point, be it ASP.Net or Unity, we have a dictionary that contains a key "data" which again contains a dictionaries of name value pairs*/

// The code from below is Linq and should work on Unity as well.
var friendIds = (dict["data"] as ArrayList)                     // Convert the "data" key of the dictionary into its underlying type (which is an ArrayList in this case)
                .Cast<Dictionary<string, object>>()             // ArrayList is not generic. Cast it to a generic enumerable where each element is of type Dictionary<string, object> 
               .Select(s =>
                            {
                                // Each element in the cast enumerable is of type dictionary.
                                // Each dictionary has two keys - "id" and "name" that correspond to the id and name properties 
                                // of the json response received when calling graph.facebook.com/me/friends.
                                // check - https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/?method=GET&path=me%2Ffriends&version=v2.0
                                // Because we only want Ids, fetch the value corresponding to the "id" key
                                object id = null;
                                if (s.TryGetValue("id", out id))
                                {
                                    return id.ToString();
                                }

                                return string.Empty;
                            });
```

I put in verbose comments to make that code a bit self explanatory. If you remove the comments, it makes for concise code. However, this is less performant than a plain for loop.

Comment: For you ... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ACKWK55Ic9M  Incredible. So beautiful. I just didn't think of linq, so beautiful.  What's the prettiest way to loop over all the ids, just a foreach ?

Comment: :) the generic 'List' method in C# has a 'ForEach' method that takes a Func delegate as a parameter and applies that delegate to each element in the list. You create your own linq extension for an IEnumerable and use it make your code look more declarative - something like this - public static void Execute<TSource>(this 'IEnumerable<TSource> source, Action<TSource> actionToExecute)      {
    if (source.Count() > 0)
    {
        foreach (var item in source)
        {
            actionToExecute(item);
        }
    }
}'   and then use this like enumerable.Execute(actionToPerform).

Comment: my bad... I've edited the answer to include the code in the above comment. cheers.

Comment: @swazza85 I really like this code but why check the Count on source in the second code?

Comment: So pretty.  TBC I'd use it like this, say  friend.Execute( MyRoutine ); ... is that right?  Actually you better include an example of how to do it  :)

Comment: @Measuring you are right - having a foreach does make checking the count redundant.  Joe yes, like that, as long as 'MyRoutine' matches the signature of 'actionToExecute' delegate.

Comment: what is **NS**Dictionary?

Comment: (LOL I'm so stupid: I was thinking of iOS programming :)  I do both.  Forget I said that :)  )

Comment: swazza, could you please show me how to get an array (I guess?) of the "data" item, and then loop through that array with a foreach?  I will increase the bonus to 100!  :)  is it something like var friends = dict.Where(s => s.Key.Equals("data")); and then foreach(var f in friends) var friendId = f.id; ?  Thanks!

Comment: :) I actually wanted to give you a complete working sample. but could not find the FB.API in the facebook c# sdk. Can you give me a link to the FB c# sdk you are using and I can put up a gist containing the working example?